# Show drupal message with ajax flags

Tags: 7, ajax, flags, status-messages

I bound an action to my flag to display a message on flagging. However because I am using AJAX flags the message is only displayed after I refresh the page.

Is there any way to make the message appear after the flag is flagged and not on page reload?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using rules ?

Comment: Yes I am! But the message is only displayed after a page refresh

Answer (score 0):

This feature already there with flags module.
[image]
Please check in your flags settings page.

Comment: I'm using flag dialog to fill out a form that is rendered in a pop up menu, this seems to break the flagged message. Also the message is limited in length. I really would like to be able to set a Drupal message

Comment: Use this module. https://drupal.org/project/js_theming
`Drupal.messages.set("The Message!", 'error');`